# Filenotfound error while running conda clean but file exists

Tags: python, conda

i am trying to clean conda by running:

```
conda clean --all
```

However, it gives the following warning:

```
 WARNING: C:\Users\myname\.conda\pkgs does not exist
```

After that, it breaks down with the following error

```
 FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\pkgs\\jupyterlab_server-2.1.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0\\site-packages\\jupyterlab_server\\tests\\translations\\jupyterlab-language-pack-es_CO\\jupyterlab_language_pack_es_CO\\locale\\es_CO\\LC_MESSAGES\\jupyterlab_some_package.json'
```

However, if i go to windows explorer, this file does exists. Is there any reason why conda would think it does not exist?

Ps: Some background information, i just installed tensorflow and got some error messages. I tried to clean, update the packages and update conda itself, but all fail. So i hope by fixing at least this error i get a bit closer to getting my conda to work again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because the file path is too long. You need to make your root/base environment in your root folder or keep its path as short as possible.